# Dynamic updating of a list-picker's contents

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

A piece of drop-dead simple code:

```
pickChosen = {};
pickSize := {"Small", "Medium", "Large"};
pickColor := {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};
pickAvailable = pickSize;
picker = ListPicker[Dynamic[pickChosen], pickAvailable];
button = Button["Click me", pickAvailable = pickColor];
Column[{Dynamic[button], Dynamic[picker]}]
```

I expect this picker to display the size list initially, and then, after clicking the button, to display the color list.  This is not what happens.  The color list is never displayed, and changing the picker assignment line to:

```
picker = ListPicker[Dynamic[pickChosen], Dynamic[pickAvailable]];
```

doesn't work either.

How can I accomplish this simply (without Manipulate, etcetera)?

Comment: `picker = Dynamic@ListPicker[Dynamic[pickChosen], pickAvailable]` and then you only need `Column[{button, picker}]`.

Comment: As an aside, it's often a good idea to use `DynamicModule[]`, even if you wish to avoid `Manipulate[]`: `DynamicModule[{pickChosen = {}, pickSize = {"Small", "Medium", "Large"}, pickColor = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"}, pickAvailable}, pickAvailable = pickSize; Column[{Button["Click me", pickAvailable = pickColor], Dynamic[ListPicker[Dynamic[pickChosen], pickAvailable]]}]]`

Comment: Thank you kuba; I thought I had tried every possible way of sprinkling 
    Dynamic over this code.

Answer (score 2):

Enlarging on the suggestion Kuba made in a comment to the question, I would do it this way, which has the additional feature of swapping the menus with each button click.

```
pickChosen = {};

Module[{indx, choice, picker, button},
  indx = 0;
  choice[0] = {"Small", "Medium", "Large"};
  choice[1] = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"}; 
  picker = Dynamic @ ListPicker[Dynamic[pickChosen], choice[indx]];
  button = Button["Click me", indx = Mod[indx + 1, 2]];
  Column[{button, picker}]]

Dynamic[pickChosen]
```

It comes up looking like this.

[image: initial]

Clinking the button changes it to this

[image: switched]

A selection can be made

[image: color_select]

Then a 2nd click on the button brings back the size menu where another selection can be made

[image: size_select]